# How to get hardware information without WMI in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

A quick grasp of the scenario,

- The application runs on a customized windows XP embedded box.
- We have to make a hardware fingerprint of the box

It turned out the customized windows XP embedded didn't have a functional WMI service. 
Is there a way to query hardware information like captions and serial numbers of CPU, chipset, motherboard, etc. without WMI?

Thanks.

Comment: In our case, what users have is a whole bundle of hardware and software. I.e. they are not supposed to replace the software, or use other hardware to run our software. Of course we'll take care of all the repairing things for such a bundle. So it's actually fine for us. Sorry I didn't mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

In general CPUID gives a lot of information.

But concerning serial numbers: You can rarely get the cpu's serial number (much less the motherboard's), it would have to be activated in the BIOS.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D3:_Processor_Serial_Number